# Parsing multiple files (same format) use `for` loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, parsing

I am developing a Python script in which I want to scan whole sub directories to find `.log` files.

To get a list of `.log` files, I can get the file names. Here is the code.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Directory to be analyse"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.log'):
```

Now, How to iterate all files in for loop and get the contents of it?

Comment: Is this a "How can I open and read a file in Python" question?

Comment: Yes. But Would like to open multiple files to parse it. There is not any fixed number of files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try;

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'path to open'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.log'):
            with open(os.path.join(root, file)) as stream:
                for lin in stream:
                    # lin containg the content of each line in the file
```

You can use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) get the full path of the file to open

Answer (score 0):

In your if block, you can open the file in a `with open` block and read each line.

```
if file.endswith('.log'):
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            pass  #Do something with each line in the opened file
    print '{} has been closed'.format(file)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok to do this with `bash`, then a one liner will do the job

```
DIR='Directory to be analyse'    
sudo find $DIR -iname \*.log -exec cat {} \;
```